# Which are the MX-5 B6 engine camshaft specifications?

Tags: mazda, camshaft

I repair my car (mx5 mk1 B6 engine 1992) recently by swapping the cylinder head with another used one. After the operation, the car won't run. Tries to start a combustion while you crank but stops and doesn't continue in order for the engine to pick up some revs.

The new cylinder head comes from a mk2 B6 engine and on the head has a code of B660, I can't find any info for this head on the internet.

However the only reason I can think of, that will cause the engine not to run after that is something different about the cam's that new head wears.

I did check spark plugs - coil pack - leads - valve timing and all look normal.

So, does anyone know whether all 1.6 B6 engines wear the same cams?

Answer (score 1):

First thing would be to check the timing between the crank and the camshaft - it has been known to be 180 degrees out and this puts the crank position sensor "out" with respect to the cam.

Comment: Still, I did the alignment as described in the book, with all marks to their correct places. So, according to your answer what exactly do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: If you have all the marks in their correct places as you say, then there is nothing to change. Is the sensor to drive the electronic ignition in the correct location and causing a spark?

Comment: Yes, it is however, I'm not sure how to check if provides a spark...

Comment: You can remove 1 spark plug, have it connected to its lead and grounded, then spin the engine and, all being well, you should see the spark. Don't try to test it with your finger - 50,000 volts can hurt or even kill you...

Comment: On the B6 engine the cam position sensor can't go the opposite way according to the engine manual. Also, I took the car to a garage and they said the timing was wrong. So, now I'm banging my head to figure it out where I was wrong when I set the timing to the engine.